# Book where two sibling have to get back to their parents from an old house after an earthquake

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember that there were two siblings, a boy and a girl, and they were moving with their parents to a big fancy old house. I remember their dad was a surgeon but was laid off. I think there was an earthquake and all of a sudden the kids are alone in the house and have to figure out how to get back to their parents. It's a mystery/adventure, and I think there is magic and monsters as well.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you remember what the cover looked like?  What kind of magic or monsters were there?